# Cubic polynomial equal to a cube

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, cubics

I've been researching cubes and I'm trying to solve this Diophantine equation over the integers.

$$ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = y^3$$where a, b, c, d are parameters for a given $n$. For example, for $n = 5$, you have$$5x^3 + 30x^2 + 90x + 100 = y^3$$

Is there any way to solve this Diophantine equation? Or does anyone know any references or links to point me to? (Either for general $a,b,c,d$ or for the specific one above). Thanks!

Also a, b, c, and d are functions of n:
$$a = n$$
$$b = (3/2)n(n-1)$$
$$c = (1/2)n(2n-1)(n-1)$$
$$d = (1/4)n^2(n-1)^2$$

It's theorized that there are no solutions (to this specific one). But I want to prove it. Surely, I can't check for every single x, I'm mainly looking for a bound on x as a function of n. Essentially, "After some finite x, it will never be a cube" ...

Comment: Suggested rewording: where a,b,c,d are integers divisible by n.

Comment: Yes, they are divisible by n. They are all known functions of n. I could post those functions if that helps?

Comment: If the form of these functions of $n$ are known it might improve the question, since as it is it includes maybe too nearly the general situation, and specific info might help in a solution.

Comment: Anything relevant to the question is likely to help.

Comment: In general such an equation represents an elliptic curve. There is a method for transforming your equation to a standard Weierstrass form. The problem of finding integer points of an elliptic curve has been solved in many cases (there exist on-line databases of sets of solutions at least for some types of curves). In general the method for finding the solutions is quite non-trivial, so can't help you there.

Comment: I was able to transform it into $$Y^3 = AX^3 + BX$$ where 
Y = ny, X = (n/2)(2x+n-1), A = n, and B = n^3(n^2-1)/4 ...

Comment: Also I made the transformation $$Z^3 = X^2 + XY$$ where Z = n^2*y, Y = n^3*x(x-1), X = (n^4/2)(2x+n-1) ... but I think the first transform is better since it's only two variables.

Comment: Also posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/178510/when-is-a-cubic-polynomial-a-cube

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Weierstrass forms have Y^2 on the left hand side for each form, which was what I noticed first when I tried researching it. I need Y^3 instead.

Comment: Yeah. But any non-singular cubic CAN be transformed (projectively!) to a Weierstrass form. I don't remember the algorithm, but it is explained in many books on elliptic curves. Unfortunately Silverman proves the existence of a Weierstrass form as a consequence of Riemann-Roch, so I can't give you a reference. Cassels, may be?

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out in a comment, you transformed the equation into $y^3=Ax^3+Bx=x(Ax^2+B)$. From that it is easy to show that any prime factor of $Ax^2+B$ which is not a prime factor of $AB$, does not divide $x$, so because of the equation it shows up with multiplicity $3$. The upshot is that you can write $Ax^2+B = Cz^3$, where $C$ is not unique but is constrained to a finite set. Now multiply this equation by $A^3C^2$ and get $V^2 = U^3 + K, V = A^2Cx, U = ACy, K =-BA^3C^2$. This is a Mordell equation and Sage and Magma will solve it, there many papers with explicit bounds, pretty much everything you want to know.

Comment: How did you get $Ax^2+B = Cz^3$?

Comment: @DerekOrr Look at the prime factorization of both sides of $x(Ax^2+B)=y^3$ and notice that any common factors of the two terms of the left hand side are factors of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a short section about equations like yours in the book *History of the Theory of Numbers*, *Volume II*, by Leonard Eugene Dickson (page 566). It deals with rational solutions not integer ones, but it might be helpful/interesting for you if you haven't already seen it.

I think I have found a counterexample to: "It's theorized that there are no solutions (to this specific one)."

I tried the case $n = 8$ on a hunch (since 8 is a cube). This gives $a = 8$, $b = 84$, $c = 420$, $d = 784$, and thus gives rise to the equation

$8x^3 + 84x^2 + 420x + 784 = y^3$

Setting $y = x + 7$ gives the integer solution $x = -3$.

Comment: The variables x and y must be positive. When x is negative, it's quite trivial in my research. When n is a cube, there's actually a formula for that one. It's the ones where n _isn't_ a cube which is tough. But thanks, I'll check out that book, maybe it's a PDF somewhere.